# How to take user input from main method to another class and method?

Tags: java

I guess my title isn't very clear and needs a code example so here you go:

```
public class ATM {


public static void main(String[] args) {

     Keypad K=new Keypad();
     K.mypin(pin);
}
}
```

That is the main method, now here is a method in another class:

```
public class Keypad{
    public void mypin(int pin) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your pin");
        pin=scan.nextInt(); 
        System.out.print(pin);  
    }
}
```

How to include `pin=scan.nextInt();` in my main method and make this work normally?
You might ask me why I want it this way and it is just because that is what I was asked to do.

Comment: This is not clear to me. Were you asked to read `pin` (using Scanner) in the `main` method and pass that value to `mypin`? Or to read the value inside the `mypin`?

Comment: To read pin in the main method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want something along those lines :

```
public class ATM {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your pin");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Keypad K=new Keypad();
        K.mypin(sc.nextInt());
    }
}

public class Keypad{
    public void mypin(int pin) {
        System.out.print(pin);  
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes more sense to me

Comment: @lealceldeiro I don't know, it follows the title and description better, but it's incoherent with the class names. Usually you'd want the Keypad to be what provides the input

Comment: I was just about to upload this as answer. As the original poster says this is an assignment and thus we should take it literally. This solves the assignment literally.

Comment: @Aaron yes, why would a `Keypad` print your pin instead of requesting it?

Comment: I guess that is the way to go Aaron, I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I see where you are coming from Andrew and I thought the same way, upon correction the instructor said he needs all scans to be done in the main method.

Comment: @Noobdeveloper it makes sense that an ATM keeps a scanner (as an input source), but it's not reasonable to print it out (or to have a separate class just to output it)

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Scanner* class with input stream *System.in*.

It is ATM class:

```
package user.input;

public class ATM {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Keypad keypad = new Keypad();

    try {
      int userPin = keypad.enterPin();
      System.out.printf("User Pin: %s", userPin);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Occured error while entering user's PIN.");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

It is Keypad class:

```
package user.input;

import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Keypad {

      public int enterPin() throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
          scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.print("Please enter your pin: ");
          int inputNum = scanner.nextInt(); // Read user input
          return inputNum;
        } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
        } finally {
          if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
          }
        }
      }
    }
```